# How to reproject map with a cascading UMN-mapserver?

Tags: dictionary, mapserver, umn-mapserver, umn

I have UMN configured as a cascading mapserver. I want it to reproject the map while cascading through UMN. How can I do that? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* as long as MapServer is configured with GDAL support then setting the projection on a layer will automatically call use this tool to reproject:

http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

Otherwise it may have to be scripted.

Your layer definition should look similar to below:

http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html

```
LAYER
  NAME "prov_bound"
  TYPE RASTER
  STATUS ON
  CONNECTION "http://www2.dmsolutions.ca/cgi-bin/mswms_gmap?"
  CONNECTIONTYPE WMS
  PROJECTION
   "init=epsg:42304"
  END
  METADATA
    "wms_srs"             "EPSG:42304"
    "wms_name"            "prov_bound"
    "wms_server_version"  "1.1.1"
    "wms_format"          "image/gif"
  END
END
```

Comment: Cascading mapserver means, that I define a layer which data comes from a different external WMS. Changing projection in this case is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Have you checked the WMS_SRS metadata property of the origin WMS? Sometimes they are set up to support multiple projections - if yes you can pass in the relevant SRS parameter in your URL calls. 
Does changing the PROJECTION in your WMS layer definition in a map file do anything?

Comment: It should just work. Setting up a WMS as a layer, is no different from setting up a shapefile as a layer.  Both have a native projection.  When you request a map in projection X if the native projections​ don't match MapServer will reproject